# HIbernate configuration file shows a warning "No route to host :connect"

Tags: xml, hibernate, orm, configuration

Hi sir i'm new to hibernate... My hibernate configuration file is as shown below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
<session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" >org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url" >jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username" >root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password" >root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml" />
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I m getting an error message like "no route to host :connect"
i am unable to fix my error. plz help me sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add port number to your connection url - default for mysql is 3306 so it looks like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" >jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp</property>
```

Check if database running under this port:
Go to Firefox browser 
localhost:3306
You should get something like:

[���
5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1�1���YIDWg%|d�ÿ÷�€����������_2w#FvA~w^OO�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order

so this is sign that is alive :)

Comment: I put port no in Hibernate configuration file... but show the same error message.. but internet connection is there ,it works smoothly but if i lost interconnection it shows me error like "no route to host:connect" and can not parse '/hibernate.cfg.xml'.